# How to use nested attributes together with attributes from the class in a Criteria with Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I have this situation:

```
country {
    and {
        rates{
                                and{
                                    between('effectiveDate', startDate, endDate)
                                    or {
                                        and {
                                            eq('hoursEligible', true)
                                            gt('hours', new BigDecimal(0))
                                        }
                                        and {
                                            eq('travelTimeEligible', true)
                                            gt('travel', new BigDecimal(0))
                                        }
                                        and {
                                            eq('mileageEligible', true)
                                            gt('mileage', new BigDecimal(0))
                                        }
                                        and {
                                            eq('expensesEligible', true)
                                            gt('expenses', new BigDecimal(0))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    }
    }
```

The thing is: hours is an attribute from a specific class, the class that has this named query. And rates is a list nested in one of the nested objects on my specific class.
When I try to use it there I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

How do I refer to the hours attribute using this named query?
Also one more question... it will return true if there is any item on rates list that returns true for this condition, correct?

That's my domain class:

```
class TravelDetail {

    Date date
    Country country
    BigDecimal hours
    BigDecimal mileage
    BigDecimal travel
    BigDecimal expenses
```

Into country I have:

```
class Country {

static hasMany = [rates: Rate
```

And into Rate I have:

```
class Rate {

    Boolean hoursEligible = Boolean.TRUE
        Boolean travelTimeEligible = Boolean.TRUE
        Boolean mileageEligible = Boolean.TRUE
        Boolean expensesEligible = Boolean.TRUE
```

Comment: show your domain classes

Comment: @injecteer, added part of the domain there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the `rate` conditions in every `and`, something like this,

```
country {
    and {
        between('effectiveDate', startDate, endDate)
        or {
            and {
                rates {eq('hoursEligible', true)}
                gt('hours', new BigDecimal(0))
            }
            .
            .
            and {
                rates {eq('expensesEligible', true)}
                gt('expenses', new BigDecimal(0))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did here, but seems like the rates block is returning true only when all of them on the list are true for the condition I made and I need it to be true . Seems like I need to do something like "rates.any". Without it it's returning the object only when all items are true

Comment: Try printing the resulting query, to have a better idea.

Comment: thank you. forgot to answer here before... but it helped and solved my problem.. just had to apply some changes.. but I had to do iterate into the rates attribute for more than once...

Comment: @Igor, if you're not very satisfied with that solution, because of many iterations; I would suggest you to go with HQL, instead. I found, it helps for complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that I would adopt a model like yours, but generally the query should look like (provided you call it against `TravelDetails`):

```
def list = TravelDetail.withCriteria{
  between 'effectiveDate', startDate, endDate
  or {
     and {
         country{ rates { eq 'hoursEligible', true } }
         gt 'hours', 0
     }
     ....
   }
}
```